# Share same singleton between multiple packages in Java GWT

Tags: java, oop, gwt, singleton

I have a GWT app. The `client` package has a number of sub-packages, like `Foo1`, `Foo2`, etc. (these packages contain multiple other classes), as well as normal classes, like `class1`, `class2`. In one of these classes in `client`, I defined a `singleton` `Init`. Now all classes under `client` (directly under it, as well as in packages like `Foo1` under `client`) share the same singleton, and modifying it in any one reflects in the others also.

However, when I try to use it in a class under the `server` package (`com.google.gwt.sample.StockWatcher.server`, client package being `com.google.gwt.sample.StockWatcher.client`), that class always gets the uninitialized singleton, that is, the changes made to it (through setters and getters) in the `client` classesare not being reflected there. I suspected that this is becuase `Init` has been defined under `client` and I am trying to use it in a different package `server`, that's why.

So I removed the `Init` class from `client`, and added it to the base `StockWatcher` package (`com.google.gwt.sample.StockWatcher`), so that all classes under `client` and `server` can use it. Bu then Java throws an error message like **No source code available for type `com.google.gwt.sample.StockWatcher.init`, did you forget to inherit a required module?**.

So it looks like other than the `public` folder and `StockWatcher.gwt.xml` files in `StockWatcher`, I can't define other classes.

So is there any way to define a singleton in one package and use the same instance in other packages as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely, the singleton [default locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault%28java.util.Locale%29) doesn't change on my computer when you change it on yours. It isn't even shared by distinct Java applications on my single machine.

More seriously, it's not about `client` vs. `server` packages, it's about where the code executes (in a browser, translated to JavaScript by GWT, vs. on your server(s))

Comment: Well, I appreciate your sense of humor, but I am new to GWT, OOP and Java, so some questions may seem a bit dumb..Can you explain why I get the given error message when I define the singleton in the `StockWatcher` folder (along with the `.gwt.xml` file and the `public` folder)

Comment: It's then outside of your GWT _source path_: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideModules

Comment: Put differently: it's not because you're using the same language client- and server-side that it's a single _app_: you're developing a client app that'll run in a browser and talk to a server-side app; and because you use the same language for both, you can also share some code (note: code, not objects; think of it as "great, I don't have to copy/paste things between my two _apps_; GWT-RPC interfaces and objects, and RequestFactory interfaces, are also such shared code)

Comment: Okay. So is there any way to make it happen? Of course, I can find the values in client and send it to the server as part of the request, but any other way, at all?

Comment: No. Now, also think that your app probably won't be used by a single person: how/when do you _synchronize_ all those _singletons_? Another metaphor: clients (browsers) talking to their bank (server) on the phone (requests/responses), just add the constraint that the bank cannot ask anything to the clients, it can only answer questions it receives from them.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Using the singleton for the client only won't cause any threading issues, right?

Comment: Yes. JS is single-threaded (don't forget that 2 tabs/windows with the same app are two instances of the app, they don't share the singleton either)

Comment: Cool. On a general note, for normal OOP projects, what is the scope of a singleton? Is it sharable only among classes within the same package, or in other packages under the same project as well?

Comment: It depends how you realize the singleton. A `static` field in Java is bound to the class and thus to the `ClassLoader` (simplifying: one per WAR, or one per desktop app). Guice has a different notion of _singleton_ (one per `com.google.inject.Injector` instance; they're not realized with `static` fields)

Comment: Umm, too complicated for me to understand these stuff now! Will take some time.. Thanks anyway..

Comment: In retrospect, I admit the question was a tad too dumb. I will give you that..:)